# More clicks while using "Noun" or "Verb" for actions?

Tags: buttons, terminology, wording, conversion-rate

“Sign up” or “Membership”? “Donate Now” or “Donations”?

You can create an action button with verb or a noun. Is there any recommendation for increasing the click-rates? Which one is better than the other for having more clicks?

Comment: "Sign up" and "register" are both verbs, do you mean "Be a member" for one of them instead?

Comment: I never ever suggest A/B testing, but I will here. Let us know what you find out.

Comment: @KenMohnkern I think that they had done an extensive A/B tests, please check the references.

Answer (score 43):

**Be a voter > Vote now**

Christopher Bryan and [Gregory Walton (2011)](http://www.pnas.org/content/108/31/12653.full.pdf) conducted a study for understanding 
if using a noun or verb statement have an influence on user motivation. According to the results of their study, participants in noun group expressed significantly more interest, 62.5%, in registering vote than participants in the verb group, 38.9%.

[Another study](https://quote.ucsd.edu/bryanlab/files/2014/07/HelpingvsHelperPaper-2.pdf) about "help" and "being helper" among children validates their hypothesis also with kids

**Take-aways from their interconnected studies :**

- “Be a member” or “Be a donor” instead of “Donate now.” is better for click rates.
- Product description with nouns are better than verbs like " When you are ready to be senior, check out our training courses" than " Check out our training courses"
- Make-up words are not effective and using common nouns are safer.

Comment: That's really interesting, do you have the link for the first study? it seems it wasn't added

Comment: +1 - interesting conclusion, without reading the article (yet) I wonder if it is because the nouns sound less imperative and the user feels less like they're being forced or told what to do. Would "Want to donate?" be as bad as "Donate now"..

Comment: @DasBeasto "...using noun-based wording to frame socially valued future behavior allows individuals, by performing the behavior, to assume the
identity of a worthy person..." I think that being someone is much important than doing something and that can be the main motivation...

Comment: On a quick related note: in this specific examples, "Become a member/donor" is a more natural-sounding verb to use here

Comment: +1, very good answer. But I do not know if we can generalize the rule that always nouns are better than verbs. It is true though, for actions that enhance our identity i.e. donator, helper etc

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst Yes, I think that creating an image of user is the key over here as you stated.

Comment: I don't think your question and your answer are talking about the same thing. Your question asks about `nouns` (i.e Donations) versus `verbs` (Donate) for calls to action. Your answer is about `noun-statements` (Become a donor) versus `verb-statements` (Donate now). I think that's a subtle difference which isn't clear in the question.

Comment: I see verbs everywhere and at every option, I don't think this answers  the question at all. Interesting (and a bit dubious), yes, but not even close to explain *nouns vs verbs*. I would be really surprised if you tell me *Membership* has more clicks than *Get [whatever benefit] now!*. As a matter of fact, I tested this many times and never, ever, ever the *noun alone* version (such as in your question) got more clicks than an action. NEVER.

Comment: ah, now I see the answer is by the OP at the same time the question was answered, so basically the OP wanted to share these studies for some reason. I'd recommend changing the question to something related to these docs

Comment: @Devin please read the research papers again, you can change if you want. it is validated with interconnected studies with intensive test.

Comment: @Devin you can propose a paper if you have valid findings and answering your own question is allowed in SE. if you have any research that proves your proposition, please share them.

Comment: the papers are good research , your question is unrelated, just that. The papers are about the relevance of semiotic significants on user's psychology on very specific contexts. Thus, *vote* is an empty word, while *Be a voter* adds a level significance for users: the user actually gets something, **s/he is a voter**. This is correct and proven in countless studies, your question is about generic instances, and therefore totally unrelated

Comment: btw, there's a reason why this is called **CTA (*Call to Action*)**

Comment: @Devin it is not only for one specific context vote and help are different words that can be used in many instances. I think that it will work with any verb action button that can be turned into a part of group. being a part of something is much more important for people according to the studies. Additionally, i would like to hear your modified question proposal, we can always change if it makes sense to the community, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All of your examples are verbs: *sign*, *register*, *donate*, *be*

Regarding click-rates; any answer given will be results for a different user base.  The only way to truly know what is more successful for your use case would be to do A/B testing with your users, and study the metrics/measures related to your site.  Perhaps you could use general statistics if it applies (as a starting point), but keep in mind that even the same users are receptive to different phrasing/terminology within different contexts. Psychology is an interesting field.

This is why personas are important.  For instance, when executing some command, mathematically-minded individuals may gravitate towards "compute", whereas managers might relate better to "process".  It all depends on *your* users.  Even subtle changes in environment may be enough to trigger certain expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The study of Christopher Bryan and Gregory Walton mentioned in another answer is interesting but there is not a universal rule of which is the best.

Sometimes you might want to show immediacy and use verbs.
Some other times you might need to have nouns for things that are related to identity.

The only thing that could help you here is **empathy**:
Take a glance at your **user persona** and then speak the phrase of the action out loud and try to put yourself in the shoes of your user.
This way is will be easier to see which option will drive a higher click/tap rate.

*Always imho the ux work is hard and try not to use a rule of thumb in all cases.

Following the safe route? Well I have yet to found one in our job :)*